# Calling onedrive methods with graph api

Tags: python, azure, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I've purchased MS Office and they give me a space on onedrive.
Now I want to operate with that via ms graph API in my **python console application** (I used python onedrivesdk before but now it is said that it is deprecated).

I have registered an application and can see it via Azure AD on portal.azure.com.

Currently I'm trying to interact with my onedrive like this:

```
tenant_id = 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx'
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(self.client_id, authority=authority, client_credential=self.client_secret)
result = app.acquire_token_silent(["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"], account=None)
if not result:
    logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"])

authToken = result['access_token']
#### Make a call to the graph API
graphResponse = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/drive',headers={'Authorization':f'Bearer {authToken}'})
if graphResponse.status_code != 200:
    print('Error code: ', graphResponse.status_code)
    print(graphResponse.text)
```

I successfully get an access token, but when I try to call **/me/drive**

I get *status_code = 400* with

> Current authenticated context is not valid for this request. This
>   occurs when a request is made to an endpoint that requires user
>   sign-in. For example, /me requires a signed-in user.  Acquire a token
>   on behalf of a user to make requests to these endpoints.  Use the
>   OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for mobile and native apps and the
>   OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for single-page web apps

I've add permissions for the application on the portal via *"API permission -> Add permission"*, but I'm unable to grant admin consent (In another ms account I have full fledged azure subscription where I'm an admin) because I'm not an admin. But who is admin of this account my MS office assigned to?

Answer (score 2):

According to the code you provided, you use [OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to complete Azure AD auth and get access token. The access token required by service principal. We cannot use the access token to call `/me/drive` endpoint. We just can use the access token to call `/users/<UserObjectIdOrUserPrincipalName}>/drive` endpoint. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta#5-use-the-access-token-to-call-microsoft-graph)

So if you want to call `/me/drive` endpoint, I suggest you use the [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). Regarding how to implement it in your application, please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/tree/e03be352914bfbd58be0d4170eba1fb7a4951d84).

Comment: Yes, /me refers to the user who is currently signed in to your app. In this case there is no user.

Comment: @jim-xu Does the sample you provided work for a console application as well?

Comment: @juunas I tried to use https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-python-daemon example but got _Insufficient privileges to complete the operation._
I think the problem is that I can't grant admin consent. I don't have this button in API permissions of my app on azure portal

Comment: Yeah, application permissions can only be granted by a Global admin/Application admin/Cloud application admin.

Comment: @amplifier As far as I knew, if you want to create a console application, you can [OAuth 2.0 device authorization grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code). Regarding how to implement it, please refer to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-devicecodeflow